# Errors accessing MSSQL form Xpages using ExtlibX - Driver or JVM not supported

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, xpages

I am trying to connect to SQL from Xpages, so I installed the latest extlibx 9 and downloaded the drivers from microsoft and added it to notes9\data\jvm\lib\ext

Now I get the following errors when trying to query SQL from my xpage:

**Error I get in xpages extlibx when using Microsoft SQL Driver sqljdbc.jar**

Error while reading the relational data

JRE (Java Runtime Environment) version 1.6 stöds inte av den här drivrutinen. Använd klassbiblioteket sqljdbc4.jar som stöder JDBC 4.0.

In English: JRE (Java Runtime Environment) version 1.6 is not supported by this driver. Use class library sqljdbc4.jar which supports JDBC 4.0.

**Error I get in xpages extlibx when using Microsoft SQL Driver sqljdbc4.jar**

Error while reading the relational data
Error while creating connection
SQL Server version 8 stöds inte av den här drivrutinen. ClientConnectionId:9195a17a-22f4-4377-a41a-be6f213b05ff

In English: SQL Server version 8 is not supported by this driver

A  few years ago there was a file called **extlib.driver.mssql_1.0.0.201109061401** which worked just fine using the same SQL server I am using now. but I cannot find that file anymore.

what should I do to get SQL queries working?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I will answer my own question here

The reason for getting these errors is because I was using the wrong driver.
There are two different version of the drivers so make sure you use the right one

This one do not work
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11774

This one works
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2505

Comment: Good one, Thx for contributing back that info

Comment: The details of the one that doesn't work also doesn't mention SQL Server 2000 (== version 8). You should also be able to use the 3.0 driver: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19847